# How to get the cosine of a waveform?

Tags: electricity, waves

I have a set of samples that represents a waveform. This waveform resembles a frequency modulated sinusoidal wave (only it is not).

I would like to invert this waveform or <strike>shift it by $2\pi$</strike> shift it by $\pi$. of course taking the cosine of samples as they are without preprocessing is wrong.

What should I do to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Shifting by 2π is the same as doing nothing. I guess it's not what you want. Can you clarify the question ?

Comment: you are right, it wouldn't do a thing! what I would like to get is a mirror reflection of the waveform over the x-axis but with the same dc-component as the original waveform (I don't want to shift it on the Y-axis).

Comment: Do you mean you have a Fourier spectrum of the waveform?

Comment: I think my problem that I was shifting by $2\pi% instead of just pi, Dah! And thanks Frédéric Grosshans. I'll share my answer with you guys.

Comment: What does this have to do with physics?

Comment: Unclear what is being asked.

Comment: ""This waveform resembles a frequency modulated sinusoidal wave (only it is not)."" Is this a joke?

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you write in the comments, perhaps you can just calculate the DC component by taking the average, subtract that, flip it over the X axis, and add the DC component back.

Comment: Yes, but how exactly do you suggest to flip it over the x-axis?

Comment: Multiply by -1?

Comment: @mbadawi23 : another way to apply @mtrencseni solution. Compute the average $a$, and replace each sample $s_i$ by $2a - s_i$

Answer (score 1):

- For each sample I calculated the angle $\theta = i * 2\pi$
- Then I added $\pi$ to $\theta$ while calculating sine and cosine components.

Comment: This solution is way more complex than @mtrencseni 's solution, at least for an angla as simple than $\pi$